# String restriction within protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

Can I represent this XSDSchema enumeration/String restriction within a protobuf enum?

```
<s:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Condition">
    <s:simpleType>
     <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="EQ" />
      <s:enumeration value="NE" />
      <s:enumeration value="GT" />
      <s:enumeration value="LT" />
      <s:enumeration value="GE" />
      <s:enumeration value="LE" />
      <s:enumeration value="LK" />
      <s:enumeration value="=" />
      <s:enumeration value="!=" />
      <s:enumeration value="&gt;" />
      <s:enumeration value="&lt;" />
      <s:enumeration value="=&gt;" />
     </s:restriction>
    </s:simpleType>
</s:element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.proto enums are named integers, but note that the last few names will barf. You would need to tweak the names in your .proto / DTO layer, but it would a pain to have to disambiguate between `"EQ"` and `"="`, `"LE"` and `"<"`

But you could map something *similar* in .proto, sure.

If you store a string that would work, but will be more bytes. Not *many* more (1 byte for the string length plus 1-4 bytes for the char-data, versus 1 byte for the enums).

Comment: ok, I thought so. This is part of a "standard" header in the protocol I am replacing, so I think it is easy to abstract away and create a wrapper that encodes it for the client.